# How-to enable X forwarding in  PuTTY

Tags: ssh, putty

I have Ubuntu next to Windows7, I am always using Ubuntu to connect remotely other computer. I use -X option to enable the GUI.

On Win7 I'm using PuTTY, how do I enable X forwarding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are starting Putty from command line or use command line tool "plink", it is the same -X option.

In Putty's GUI, the option is under category Connection / SSH / X11, Enable X11 forwarding.